# C# storing multiple string in a custom list

Tags: c#, list

I have the need to store several strings and retrieve each one separately.

eg.

```
string one = "String One";
string one = "String Two";
string one = "String Three";
string one = "String Four";
```

I am currently using a custom LIST (http://pastebin.com/AW5jqfM0) to perform this, however, I am having difficulty finding the most efficient way to store all of these variables and return a different string formatting.

eg.

```
    if(stringInput = "")
    {
       list<>.add(customMethod(one, two, three, ""));
    }
    else
    {
       list<>.add(customMethos(one, two, three, four));
    }
```

I do not know if this is the best way to accomplish this task. Would it be more efficient for me to create a list type for each return type?

I hope I have been clear!

Comment: I suggest you yo use a list/container of strings, you do not need a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an extension method to create your custom ToString(), https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This will allow you to use a normal list an customise the output.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string MyToStringMethod(this IEnumerable<string> myNormalListOfStrings)
    {
         //my method
    }
}
```